# mllr_solve 'Error reading byte order magic number' on Windows

Tags: windows, cmusphinx

I'm following the Adapting Default Acoustic model tutorial and have hit a error running mllr_solve.

```
INFO: main.c(382): -- 1. Read input mean, (var) and accumulation.
ERROR: "pio.c", line 434: fread() failed; retrying...
: No error
ERROR: "swap.c", line 79: error while reading bo_magic
ERROR: "s3io.c", line 177: Error reading byte order magic number
ERROR: "s3io.c", line 265: Error reading header for en-us-8khz\means
FATAL: "main.c", line 392: Couldn't read en-us-8khz\means
```

I compiled sphinxtrain and sphinxbase using Visual Studio 2017 using 'Release\Win32'.

Is there anyway to change the means/variances files or change s3io.c?

Comment: Academic software is, erm, different.  "fread() failed" is where it starts to go downhill, it tries to plow on and nothing good happens next.  Standard GIGO, this is a bad data problem.

Comment: @Ben It is trying to read the magic number from 'means' file. which should be 0x44, 0x33, 0x22, 0x11 sequence of bytes in file.
fread is trying to read the 4 bytes and it is failing to do so.

It appears that, your 'means' file is incomplete. 
When fread is attempting to read the 4 bytes, it is failing because file has no 4 bytes at that point.

What do you mean when you say change s3io.c? You can certainly edit the code and skip the magic number validation. But that is irrelevant since it appears that "means" file is incomplete.

Comment: I have two valid means files that I downloaded from the repository. I'll look into what fread is doing and see what else I can change. I hoped this was a known problem on the Windows build

Answer (score 1):

This issue is most likely caused by runtime incompatibility between sphinxbase and sphinxtrain. Time to blame Windows designers, not software

https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/faq/#q-pocketsphinx-crashes-on-windows-in-_lock_file

Comment: I've finally come back to this and both sphinxbase and sphinxtrain are being compiled with MultiThreadedDLL as suggested in the docs. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Sure, you can try to debug this. A bit of knowledge about ABI is required though